# How to make a Custom marker on google maps disappear if it is not in focus

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Some of the markers in google maps appear when zoomed in. However, when a user drag the map into a different place, the marker disappears, and when you drag it again on the previous place, the marker starts to animate in front of you (I hope you are getting what I'm trying to say). I want to know if there is such a way to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens in Google Maps Android API v2 on street names, parks, etc.

There is no support for marker transparency as of this writing. You will have to code it yourself: posting to Handler until the animation finishes and setting new icon every "frame" with increasing opacity.